# Django query with AVG and GROUP BY

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-1.4

My Django-foo isn't quite up to par to translate certain raw sql into the ORM.

Currently I am executing:

```
SELECT avg(<value_to_be_averaged>), <id_to group_on> 
FROM <table_name> 
WHERE start_time >= <timestamp> 
GROUP BY <id_to group_on>;
```

In Django I can do:

```
Model.objects.filter(start_time__gte=<timestamp>).aggregate(Avg('<value_to_be_averaged>'))
```

but that is for all objects in the query and doesn't return a query set that is grouped by the  id like in the raw SQL above. I've been fiddling with .annotate() but haven't made much progress. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is Model.objects.filter(start_time__gte=<timestamp>).values(<id_to group_on>).annotate(average=Avg(<value_to_be_averaged>)) right?

Comment: This new query is looking good but is there an easy way to have the result be {average, name} instead of {average, id} where name is the name of the object associated with this id?